# Correct Approach for Serving Javascript Files via Node.js Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to write a node application which serves crjavascript code to a static webpage. The code would then be evaluated in the webpage. Similar to [this example](http://labs.ft.com/2012/08/basic-offline-html5-web-app/), but with node instead of php. Server application looks like this:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var js;
    //send back all libraries
    fs = require('fs');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    //var paths = ['javascript.js'];
    js = fs.readFileSync('example.js').toString();
    res.end('_js(\'{"message": " ' + js + '"}\')');
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// put a message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

While client code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: "_js",
                cache: false,
                timeout: 20000,
                success: function(data) {
                    var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(dataJson['message']);
                    eval(dataJson['message']);
                    alert(test);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

example.js currently contains one line `alert('hello world')`. The idea would be to send this line of code to index.html using the ajax query and then run it. However, I keep getting errors based on this line because of the ungainly mess of apostrophes and brackets:

```
res.end('_js(\'{"message": " ' + js + '"}\')');
```

I was thinking there must be a better way to do this?

Comment: res.json() if you don't mind using Express, or maybe JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a hard requirement to serve the javascript via ajax, it would be much simpler for you to use a node based web-server, such as [expressjs](http://expressjs.com), which allows you to easily serve [static content](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).

Comment: Thanks. Also a great idea and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved by using `res.end('_js(\'{"message": " ' + escape(js) + '"}\')');` on the server and `eval(unescape(dataJson['message']))` on the client. Apologies for posting but I was getting nowhere for over an hour before figuring a solution...